# Filtros de Tabelas com jQuery

Tags: jquery, tabela-html

Implementei um filtro de tabelas com com jQuery, conforme código abaixo, porém gostaria de implementar um contador dos retornos de registro, conforme pesquisar.

```
$(function(){
    $(".input-search").keyup(function(){
        //pega o css da tabela 
        var tabela = $(this).attr('alt');
        if( $(this).val() != ""){
            // OCULTA VALORES NÃO ENCONTRADOS.
            $("."+tabela+" tbody>tr").hide();
            // EXIBE OS RESULTADOS ENCONTRADOS.
            $("."+tabela+" td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();

        } else{
            //EXIBE TABELA TODA 
            $("."+tabela+" tbody>tr").show();

        }
    }); 
});
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "contains-ci": function(elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }

});
```

Comment: A tabela é gerada através de consulta à base de dados?

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente o que precisa, acho que deu para resolver. Adicionei o contador logo no inicio para ter acesso no escopo, logo em seguida zeramos ele para que não pegue resquício de outras contagens. Depois, quando o item é exibido, adicionamos ele a contagem para ter o total de registros exibidos.

Código atualizado:

```js
    $(function() {

        var contador = 0;

        $(".input-search").keyup(function() {

            contador = 0;

            //pega o css da tabela 
            var tabela = $(this).attr('alt');
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                // OCULTA VALORES NÃO ENCONTRADOS.
                $("." + tabela + " tbody>tr").hide();
                // EXIBE OS RESULTADOS ENCONTRADOS.
                $("." + tabela + " td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();

                contador = $("." + tabela + " td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").length;

            } else {
                //EXIBE TABELA TODA 
                $("." + tabela + " tbody>tr").show();

            }
        });
    });

    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
        "contains-ci": function(elem, i, match, array) {
            return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: _Valeu_ Bruno_,

Contudo implementei as mudanças sugeridas por você,porém contador não esta incrementando,não entendi por que você colocou o contador dentro de um IF.outra questão, usando seguinte código para apresentar valor desso contador  '$("#resultado").html(resultado);' declarei um DIV no html para exibi logo após tabela .
Desde já valeu

Comment: Que bom que deu certo Rafael. O IF ali era para caso o objeto não existisse, não iria adicionar no contador. O jQuery não retorna erro caso a expressão do show não obtivesse objeto, aí uma forma de validar se ele existe é verificar com .length. Se o objeto que fosse pego pelo código fosse igual a 1, incrementava 1 no contador.

Comment: Então Bruno,como disse o contador não esta incrementando,já coloquei display de INPUT do variável contador  para verificar  é nada.Não sei ficou tão claro minha dúvida.Gostaria de implementar um contador toda vez que realizar um pesquisa me retornaria total de registro na tabela.

Comment: Faça um teste, coloque depois do fechamento do else {} <-- um console.log(contador) e veja o console se está exibindo algum valor. Se estiver, aponte a saída para o html, exemplo $("#contador").html(contador);

Comment: Realmente nada Brother
  '} else{
            //EXIBE TABELA TODA 
            $("."+tabela+" tbody>tr").show();   
        }
        console.log(contador) ;
        alert("Teste "+contador);
    }); '
Coloquei até alert...será que por conta que esta resetando variável logo após trecho '$(".input-search").keyup(function(){ '

Comment: Atualizei o código, realmente estava errado, veja se agora vai dar certo. Não sei de onde havia tirado, mas imaginei um loop ali e não tem, basta apenas conta a quantidade de itens que serão exibidos.

Comment: Valeu aparente funcionou,porém com realizei alguns teste,percebi que na medida que vai digitando no campo de busca,contador apresenta alguns inconsistências s.Irei estudar um forma de implementar de forma melhor.Até fiz no PHP,porém com estou aprendendo JQuery irei implementar com ele.Obrigado